# Haskell: 'No instance for' arising from a trivial usage of Regex library

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Following the (accepted) answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028764/multiline-matching-in-haskell-posix), I am expecting the following to work:

```
Prelude Text.Regex.Posix Text.Regex.Base.RegexLike Text.Regex.Posix.String> makeRegex ".*"
```

(`makeRegex` is a shortcut for `makeRegexOpts` with predefined options)

However, it doesn't:

```
<interactive>:1:0:
    No instance for (RegexMaker regex compOpt execOpt [Char])
      arising from a use of `makeRegex' at <interactive>:1:0-13
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for
      (RegexMaker regex compOpt execOpt [Char])
    In the expression: makeRegex ".*"
    In the definition of `it': it = makeRegex ".*"
Prelude Text.Regex.Posix Text.Regex.Base.RegexLike Text.Regex.Posix.String> make
Regex ".*"::Regex

<interactive>:1:0:
    No instance for (RegexMaker Regex compOpt execOpt [Char])
      arising from a use of `makeRegex' at <interactive>:1:0-13
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for
      (RegexMaker Regex compOpt execOpt [Char])
    In the expression: makeRegex ".*" :: Regex
    In the definition of `it': it = makeRegex ".*" :: Regex
```

And I really don't understand why.

**EDIT**

Haskell Platform 2009.02.02 (GHC 6.10.4) on Windows

**EDIT2**

```
Prelude Text.Regex.Base.RegexLike Text.Regex.Posix.String> :i RegexMaker
class (RegexOptions regex compOpt execOpt) => RegexMaker regex compOpt execOpt source | regex -> compOpt execOpt, compOpt -> regex execOpt, execOpt -> regex compOpt where
  makeRegex :: source -> regex
  makeRegexOpts :: compOpt -> execOpt -> source -> regex
  makeRegexM :: (Monad m) => source -> m regex
  makeRegexOptsM ::
    (Monad m) => compOpt -> execOpt -> source -> m regex
        -- Defined in Text.Regex.Base.RegexLike
```

Comment: Not reproducible for `makeRegex ".*" :: Regex`.

Comment: I didn't make it up, I swear! How is that possible? Any ideas where to look?

Comment: Upgrade all your packages maybe? And upgrade GHC to 6.12.

Comment: @KennyTM: Well, I started from trying to set up Haskell Platform on 6.12 on Ubuntu. Totally failed. Ended up with Haskell Platform 2009.02.02 (GHC 6.10.4) on Windows. Which by all means should work!

Comment: @artermave: Try `cabal update` then `cabal upgrade <outdated-package>`?

Comment: What does :i RegexMaker tell you?

Comment: `:i RegexMaker` output added to original question

Answer (score 4):

Your first try does not work because makeRegex has a polymorphic return type (called `regex`). Since there is no instance of RegexMaker for abitrary types, you get the message you do.

To make it work you need to specify a return type. It seems like you figured that out yourself because that's what you did in your second try, which incidentally works when I try it out in my ghci.

Edit: I should add that the most straight-forward way to use regexen is to just use `=~` and not bother with makeRegex at all. For example:

```
> "lale" =~ ".*" :: Bool
True

> "lale" =~ "lo" :: Bool
False

> "lale" =~ "l." :: String
"la"

> "lale" =~ "l." :: [String]
["la","le"]
```

Comment: I know about `=~` but since I in fact need to ignore case in pattern (which is not mentioned in the question), I am constructing regex on my own

Comment: So `::Regex` thing works for you guys. That is a great news - means my understanding of type classes is not totally broken - but then, how come it does not work for me? This is weird.